# SICP exercise 1.17 issue

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm doing exercise 1.18 in SICP and I face some trouble. The goal is to make a procedure based on 2 previous exercises. This procedure implements so-called Russian peasant method (or Ancient Egyptian multiplication). I wrote a code, but one procedure just doesn't want to execute. Here's my code:

```
#lang sicp
(define (double a) (+ a a)) 
(define (halve a) (/ a 2)) 

(define (r_m a b)
  (iter a b 0))
  
(define (iter a b n)
    (cond ((= b 0) 0)
          ((even? a) (iter (halve a) (double b) (+ n b)))
          (else (iter (halve a) (double b) n))))
```

So, when I call my procedure `(r_m)` with such arguments `(r_m 13 19)` it stops after 1st iteration.
`(iter (halve a) (double b) (+ n b)` (with arguments 13 and 19) gives this result: `iter (13/2) 38 19`

After that, program tries to check if 13/2 is odd. But it can't check such number (13/2), because `odd?` expects an integer, not this undone division.

For some reason, the `halve` procedure doesn't work when called. I don't really understand why, because other procedures (`double` and simple `+ n b`) work fine.

Thank you in advance and I hope my grammar doesn't hurt you too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your program.  Apart from anything else, even if `halve` worked the way you want it to work, how would `b` become zero?  This is not the only problem!

However the particular case of `halve` happens because you are assuming programming languages to do what they normally do: incorrect arithmetic which is convenient for the machine, rather than correct arithmetic which is convenient for humans.  Scheme tries hard to do *correct* arithmetic.  What, mathematically, is 13/2?  It's not 6, or 7, or 3, it's 13/2, or 6 + 1/2: it's a rational number, not an integer.

If you want the next integer below 13/2, the way you want to get it is by subtracting 1 before you divide: (halve (- 13 1)) is 6, exactly.  So if you change that `cond` clause to have `(halve (- a 1))` your program will be closer to working (but, in fact it will then fail to terminate, so in a sense it will be further from working...).

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed the `halve` section adding a `cond`  to check if the number is odd(do (- a 1) if so) or not. And then changed this `(cond ((= b 0) 0)` to this `(cond ((= a 0) n)`. The program now works as intended. For numbers 13 and 19 it returns the right answer: 247. Thank you kindly!